# how to import with full database with split export files

Tags: oracle, datapump, impdp, expdp

My client uses the following script to take backup with export datapump:

```
expdp system/******** logfile=exp_pdco1mob00_full_12232013.txt directory=ABC
 dumpfile=exp_pdco1mob00_full_1_12232013.dmp,exp_pdco1mob00_full_2_12232013.dmp,exp_pdco1mob00_full_3_12232013.dmp,exp_pdco1mob00_full_4_12232013.dmp
full=y exclude=statistics filesize=5g
```

They give me backup and I have to import full backup on a new machine to debug the error. Can anyone help me how to import full database with impdp?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm sure there's a general guide somewhere online. Do you have a more specific question about obstacles you've encountered?

Comment: Thank you so much i have done by using oracle document

Answer (score 2):

The export was taken using datapump and has been split into 4 files, each file is 5GB or less.

---

To perform the import on the new machine you will have to do the following:

- Copy the files to the target machine.
- Since the export is done using datapump, you will need to create a directory on the database.

Create directory statement, replace *PATH* with the location of copied files

```
SQL> Create or Replace Directory ABC as 'PATH';
```

- Use the below command to import the full backup/dump.
  As the dump files are made split, you will have to specify all files under dumpfile parameter

Import command

```
IMPDP directory=ABC dumpfile=exp_pdco1mob00_full_1_12232013.dmp,
exp_pdco1mob00_full_2_12232013.dmp,
exp_pdco1mob00_full_3_12232013.dmp,
exp_pdco1mob00_full_4_12232013.dmp 
logfile=IMPORT_DUMP full=y
```

Comment: Can we use wildcards like "*"? I have several files but they have almost same names, except part numbers. It may go like exp01,exp02 ... etc. and i want to use like exp0*